# Wordpress CSS not registering in editor

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, editor

I am entering this code into the wordpress css editor in the dashboard and it's not doing anything. Is there a reason for this not working?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #product_header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff!important;
        height: 200px!important;
        margin-top: 50px!important;
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're using any cache / minify plugins, make sure they're cleared. And view the site at less than 600px?

Comment: I'm using private browser to test so there is no cached data and testing on chrome's mobile responsive testing platform, but still no luck :/

Comment: Dang :( Sounds like it's time for cup of coffee at least... the only thing left is check the spelling of `#product_header` matches the code and is an `id` not a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme you use, some themes block you from editing the css if you're not premium.

Otherwise you could try to edit it locally and then upload it again.
the css of the theme is usually located at 
/main-dir/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/css/

[For more information see the Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

Comment: Do not edit the theme CSS, but create a child theme or you will lose your changes after updating the theme.

Comment: This is a custom made theme built with "Roots" theme builder so it shouldn't have any limitations on it. I just can't access the original files right now and need to make updates. Very frustrating